# Compound label in v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

```
<v-select
                v-model="pack"
                :debounce="250"
                :options="packs"
                placeholder="pack"
                :disabled="loading"
                label="id">
        </v-select>
```

Hello, i have a problem in a v-select. I have pack (computed property pack in vue, with id and name), and when a put in label id or name like in the code, the code works fine; but when i try to put the compound label (id - name), i cannot. I have tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: `the code below` - did you forget to put this code in?

Comment: sorry, it is an error, i was talking about the code i put in my comment.

Comment: You've made no comment either .. so, where is this code?

Comment: In my post, sorry but english is not my main language.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<v-select
      v-model="pack"
      :debounce="250"
      :items="packs"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
      placeholder="pack"
      label="id">
  </v-select>
```

Comment: Doesnt work, it shows the same.

Comment: Can you give me more information on how you get "packs" and what the array looks like?

Comment: packs is an array of object, the objects have only id and name.

Comment: I can't help you than. I'm sorry, it works for me.